What does "total canon killer" mean?
Lyla is making a statement about Spot:

Lyla: Hey, guys? Guys? He's making his own portals. He can jump
wherever he wants. He could be a total canon killer.

What does "total canon killer" mean?

There are certain events that apparently need to occur in each Spider-verse universe in order for them to remain in sync with their counterparts. Incredibly dramatic changes are apparently allowable, but certain, very specific events are immutable, for instance that Uncle Ben needs to die in order to inspire Spider-Man or that a police captain needs to die.

MIGUEL: They are The Canon. Chapters that are a part of every spider’s story, every time.
[The nodes expand to project big moments in their shared lives: A spider bites Peter Parker... Peter B. Parker... Gwen... Miles...]
MIGUEL: Some good, some bad, some very bad.
[Uncle Ben dies in Peter’s arms. Peter dies in Gwen’s arms. Scores of Spiders losing loved ones, including Miles losing --
MILES: Uncle Aaron...
[A node opens to show a classic comics moment where CAPTAIN
GEORGE STACY saves a RED-SHIRTED CHILD from FALLING RUBBLE,
only to be crushed himself...]
MIGUEL: This one -- Event ASM90 -- a police captain close to Spider-Man dies
saving a kid from falling rubble during a battle with an archnemesis...

The rip in the spider-verse caused by Kingpin's Super Collider (or Spot's newfound ability to transcend universes at will) is a threat to everyone and everything in every universe. Miguel explains that breaking 'The Canon' leads to the creation of quantum holes which ultimately lead to the collapse of a universe and the death of everyone in it.
Someone who can breach canon with little or no understanding (or care) for the consequences, leaving a trail of unimaginable destruction behind him, would be a "canon killer".
